# Replace Y text value by image on mpandroidchart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I need to replace all Y left values by 4 images, the Y values are fixed numbers, each number represent a image, how to do it?

[image]

```
val lineData = LineData(dataSet)
        chart.setNoDataText("Nenhum treino computado")
        chart.setDrawBorders(false)
        chart.setPinchZoom(false)
        chart.isDoubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
        chart.data = lineData
        chart.description = desc
        chart.setGridBackgroundColor(R.color.graphGride)
        chart.setDrawGridBackground(false)
        chart.legend.textColor = ActivityCompat.getColor(this, R.color.graphLabel)
        chart.axisLeft.gridColor = ActivityCompat.getColor(this, R.color.graphLabel)
        chart.xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
        chart.xAxis.textColor = ActivityCompat.getColor(this, R.color.graphLabel)
        chart.xAxis.axisLineColor = ActivityCompat.getColor(this, R.color.graphLabel)
        chart.xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true)
        chart.xAxis.labelCount = dateList.size
        chart.axisLeft.labelCount = 3
        chart.axisLeft.axisMinimum = 0f
        chart.axisLeft.axisMaximum = 3f
        chart.invalidate()
```